# Android notification bar persists on the all Application screen(never goes)

Tags: java, android

I have a screen in my app with a button to set date/time in the OS. I use startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS)) to open the android's date/time screen .

After setting the date/time , i return to my app screen using the back button in the android's status(notification) bar. After this, the notification bar never dissappears from my app screens. Its persistent until i restart my application. Is there a way to remove the notification bar?

I have added the line "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" to all my activities and even at at the application level(just inside  )
But still it never goes

Here is a part of my manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.cyberonics.progsoundapp.ui.AlarmSettingScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_setting_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

I also have the following code in my activity class

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) before SetContentView()
```

Is there anything else i am missing? 
Request your guidance on this

Thank you